# c language, multiples of 5 being saved on a prime vector

Tags: c, vector, primes

I'm a newbie and i'm currently making a program that asks the user a number and if the number is a prime it gets stored in a vector, if the vector isn't completed the code doesn't stop. The only problem is that it stores multiples of 5, like 15, 25, 35, etc in it. How can i make it stop storing these multiples of 5? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int primes[5], num, i, count = 0, x = 0;

    do
    {
        printf ("Type a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count = 2)
        {
            primes[x] = num;
            x++;
        }
    }
    while (x < 5);

    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        printf("%d ", primes[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (count = 2)` -> `if (count == 2)`

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work out, it made my code run in an infinite loop

Comment: You have a different logic error there. The loop only ends when you've stored 5 primes. If it never get to 5 it'll never end.

Comment: I know, but the problem I have with the code in the way it is is only about it storing numbers that are multiples of 5 and they shouldn't belong there. The code is supposed to keep running until there are 5 positions in the vector

Comment: `if (count = 2)` is the same as `if(2)`, it is always true. That's the reason any number you typed would be stored in the array. How you deal with filling up the array and exiting the loop is a different problem. You're also not resetting count in each iteration of the loop which is another problem.

Comment: Another problem with `count` is that its value isn't resetted to zero at the  beginning of the loop. I'd suggest at least to move the logic of prime checking into a separate function `is_prime`, one you could immediately return from as soon as `num % i` is 0.

Comment: Also, don't forget to check the value returned by `scanf`. You maty want to know if a number was actually read or if the stream ended.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is the assignment operator, not the equality check operator. You should use `==` to check if the `count` is 2:

```
if (count = 2)
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work out, it made my code run in an infinite loop

Comment: @Matheus_Felipe_c `x++` probably shouldn't be inside the `if`

Comment: Well, it has to be there if they want to store *only* the primes...

Answer (score 0):

You write

```
        for (i = 1; i<= num; i++)
```

a prime number is a number that is divisible only by one and itself, your primality test divides your number by all numbers (includind 1 and `num` itself) so every number (prime or not) will probe to be compound.

Your primality test must start at 2 and end at most at `num - 1` to avoid dividing the number by one and by itself (all numbers are divisible by themselves and by one) as in

```
        for (i = 2; i < num; i++)
```

this should solve your problem... but it will be very inefficient, as you are dividing by all the even numbers, and it is not necessary to divide it by all the even numbers (except for 2 itself)  Also, you can stop at a number that is below or equal to `sqrt(num)`, rounded down to the previous integer, because if the number has a factor above that number, for sure you have already found a factor below it (and both multiply pairwise to give you the number).

Also, there's a problem here:

```
        if (count = 2)
```

This is a valid C statement, but it most probably don't do what you intend, as the `=` operator is the **Assignment Operator**, and not the logical equal operator (which is spelled `==`)  You need to change, because as shown, you are assigning `count` the value `2`, and this is always true, by definition of the assignment operator, if you assign something different than zero, it will result in a true result, so your if will execute allways the body of its true part.

Anyway, many variables it's not clear what you are using them for, (`count` is one of these) as you assign, increment it, but you don't use its value anywhere (except the `if` statement above, and in a wrong way)